# Interpretation of additional arguments to Ruby's Kernel::system method

Tags: ruby

Why does the first excerpt succeed and the second fail?

```
system 'emacs', '--batch', '--quick', '--eval="(require \'package)"'

system 'emacs --batch --quick --eval="(require \'package)"'
```

(If it matters, I'm executing the code on Mac OS X Mountain Lion with Ruby version 1.8.7 and Emacs version 22.1.1.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those two `system` calls are different in ways that you may not expect. A quick example will probably explain the difference better than a bunch of words and hand waving. Start with a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

I'll call that `pancakes.sh` because I like pancakes more than foo. Then we can step into `irb` and see what's going on:

```
>> system('./pancakes.sh --where-is="house?"')
--where-is=house?
>> system('./pancakes.sh', '--where-is="house?"')
--where-is="house?"
```

Do you see the significant difference? The single argument form of [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) hands the whole string to `/bin/sh` for processing and `/bin/sh` will deal with the double quotes in its own way so the program being called will never see them. The multi-argument form of `system` doesn't invoke `/bin/sh` to process the command line so the arguments are passed as-is with double quotes intact.

Back to your `system` calls. The first one will send this exact argument to `emacs` (note that Ruby will take care of converting `\'` to just `'`):

```
--eval="(require 'package)"
```

and `emacs` will try to evaluate `"(require 'package)"`; that looks more like a string than an elisp snippet to me and evaluating a string literal doesn't do much of anything. Your second will send this to `emacs`:

```
--eval=(require 'package)
```

and `emacs` will complain that it

> Cannot open load file: package

Note that my elisp knowledge is buried under about 20 years of rust and forgetfulness so some of the `emacs` details may be a bit off.

Comment: Might this be a good addition to your answer? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html

Comment: @squiguy: The only time I use Shellwords is if I need to parse a command line [the way a shell would](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellsplit).

Comment: I thought `shellescape` might be helpful, but I may have read the question/your answer too quickly.

Comment: But you can bypass the whole escaping problem by using the multi-argument form of `system` instead of the single string form.